# International equivalents of the SEC's EDGAR (SEDAR in Canada) database?

Tags: dataset, finance, xbrl

Are there equivalents of the SEC's EDGAR (filing database) for European companies? Or any other region for that matter? For the UK I've found the "Companies House".

```
http://www.sedar.com/homepage_en.htm
https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/accessing-edgar-data.htm
http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/en_monthlyaccountsdata.html
```

I'm searching for (XBRL) filings outside the US, preferably for European entities.

Comment: Have a look https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/wiki/display/CEFDIGITAL

Comment: Hi Mohit, thank you for the input. I'm figuring out how this portal works atm.. Perhaps you've got any tips on how to get to corporate financial data?

Comment: @Williem Yes i do I've worked something similar for australians

Comment: Let me know the requirement is more  detail, so that i can give you better answer , what exactly is the transaction you want to do??

Comment: @mohitsharma Hi Mohit, just to clarify my question: I'd like to get something similar to the 10-K and 10-Q filings of the SEC (containing quarterly or annual financial statements), but then for European companies. Does this portal offer this kind of information? For simplicity, can I get for example an annual report for the company "Royal Dutch Shell"  through this portal?

Answer (score 6):

- **United Kingdom:** https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/search/companies
- **Ireland:** www.cro.ie
- **France:** www.infogreffe.fr
- **Germany:** https://www.unternehmensregister.de/ureg
- **Italy:** www.registroimprese.it
- **Switzerland:** https://www.zefix.ch/
- **European Business Register (EBR):** http://www.ebr.org/
- **GLO Filings:** www.glofilings.com

Answer (score 0):

So far there is no one single aggregator for EU business data. 
But you can get data on the country basis.

In the UK that's Companies House - https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/companies-house
In France, it's the Registre du commerce et des sociétés https://www.infogreffe.fr/societes/
In Germany, it's the Unternehmensregister https://www.unternehmensregister.de/ureg/?language=de&submitaction=language

For other countries there is a list on the Companies House website: https://www.gov.uk/government/pu...

Comment: Thanks for the additional suppliers, unfortunately these are all paid services. My main goal is to perform bulk analysis of the financials, so with these data suppliers it would become a very costly operation. If anyone can help with additional free to use data suppliers, that would be great. BTW your last link (https://www.gov.uk/government/pu...) seems to be broken, could you repost that one perhaps?

Comment: @Willem old but i believe he wanted to post:
https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/overseas-registries/overseas-registries#registries-in-europe
most of them dont have financial filings available. Did you ever find where we can find those filings?

Comment: @FilipCornelissen Forgive me for being blunt: my conclusion has been that the only financially civilized nation in the world remains the United States. What SEC offers with the EDGAR product is uniquely competent. SEDAR (Canada) is comparable. Rest of the world, including Europe, is way behind in terms of serving the public interest through standardized financial reporting on listed corporations. No surprise we generally don't invest our own savings. A waste to society in terms of understanding what corporations actually do. My advise: stick to EDGAR, if the company matters it will be there.

Comment: @FilipCornelissen It's like comparing the middle ages to the renaissance. In the dark, or in the light.

Comment: @Willem Indeed, sadly very true